# Certificates for authentication and signing

Tags: oauth-2.0, digital-signature, x509certificate, pki

I have a client server scenario.

I have both thick client and a thin client (browser) which communicates with my server.

My thick client  uses X-509 system certificate for client certificate authentication scenario and communicates with the server

Also this certificate is used for used to generate signed URL (with expiration time) for my thin client to communicate with my server which is used for integrity and authorization purpose. I also have a token based approach for authentication purpose in this case.

Now i want to complete move my authentication mechanism to OAuth based flow using client credentials or auth code based.

I understand that authentication and authorization can be moved to OAuth based communication. But how do i move my signing (digital signature) based use case to OAuth from certificate based ?

I don't think there is any other way than to use certificate based PKI mechanism for digital signing. Can the private and public keys be distributed other than the certificates ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

> Can the private and public keys be distributed other than the certificates ?

You may generate key pair using openssl (command line - openssl.exe) or any cryptographic library or CSP of crypto device.  Instead of distributing it, you may have a piece of software which user may use at his end to generate public key and private key and share public key if required and store private key securely.  But question remains how user would store private key securely and there comes certificate storage formats like PFX which is password protected (encrypted using password you provide) or storing private key in smartcard or usb token which are cryptographic devices.  You may program these devices to generate our own keys and not necessarily store certificate issued by CA.

For browser based access to user's private key, you may need to use browser extension.
Refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885) for accessing user's keys from browser for authentication.